# A game involving a set $A={1,...,n}$ where the goal for one player is for the addition of numbers she chooses to be composite and other opposite.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinatorial-game-theory

I was just doing the following problem:

> Alice and Bob play the following game: Alice picks a set $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for some natural number $n\ge2$. Then, starting with Bob, they alternatively choose one number from the set $A$, according to the following conditions: initially Bob chooses any number he wants, afterwards the number chosen at each step should be distinct from all the already chosen numbers and should differ by $1$ from an already chosen number. Alice wins if the sum of all the numbers that she has chosen is composite. Otherwise, Bob wins. Decide which player has a winning strategy.

I state that $k$ is the sum of the numbers which Bob picked and $l$ is the sum of the numbers that Alice picked.

We have that $k+l=\frac{(n+1)\cdot n}2$ is an invariable so $2l=n^2+n-2k$, $l=\frac{n^2-n-2k}2$

If Bob originially picked $x$ then we have that:

$k=x+(x+1\text{ or }x-1)+(x+1\text{ or }x-1\text{ or }x-2\text{ or }x+2)$

And this is as far as I got. Could you please show me how to finish off the question using the maximum amount of what I have already written?

Comment: sorry editing now

Comment: Your first use of $k$ and $l$ seems to have them the final totals for Alice and Bob.  The next use of $k$ seems to be Bob's total after three turns.  Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for picking me up on that, I believe that it should be clarified now

Comment: You are still assuming that Bob gets three turns, which is only true when $n=5$ or $6$.  His third pick could be as large as $x+4$ or as small as $x-4$ in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alice wins.  I think if the problem has a solution she must win because I don't see how you could prove that Bob wins all numbers.  There could be a large number where it just works out that Alice wins.  The task is to prove that Alice can win.  The easiest way is to find some small $n$ that she can win.

The outcome of a particular game is determined when the first person picks $1$ or $n$ because there are no choices left.

Alice wins with $n=8$.
If Bob picks an end, Alice gets $16$ or $20$
If Bob picks $2$, Alice picks $3$, the other of $1,4$ from Bob and gets $18$ or $21$
If Bob picks $3$, Alice picks $2$.  Bob picking $1$ gives Alice $20$, so he must pick $4$.  Alice picks $5$, Bob $6$, Alice $1$ and gets $16$.
If Bob picks $4$, Alice picks $3$.  Bob picking $2$ lets Alice pick $1$ and get $18$.  Bob picking $5$ lets Alice pick $6$ and get $18$.
If Bob picks $5$, Alice picks $6$.  Bob $4$ and Alice $3$ give $18$, Bob $2$ and Alice $1$ give $18$
If Bob picks $6$ we have Alice $7$, Bob $5$, Alice $4$, Bob $3$, Alice $8$ getting $20$
If Bob picks $7$ Alice picks $6$, Bob $5$ Alice $8$ gets $18$.

All of the cases I gave Bob only one choice lose immediately after the other because it is an end.

Comment: I think I have found an error in what you are saying, if Bob picks 2, and Alice picks 1, then Bob will pick 3, Alice will pick 4, Bob will pick 5, and Alice 6, hence Alice will have an addition of 11, which is prime

Comment: If Bob picks 2, and Alice picks 3 and Bob picks 1, then Alice will pick 4, Bob will pick 5 and Alice 6, which gives an addition of 13, again prime

Comment: However thanks a lot for your response :)

Comment: @Michael:  You are correct.  It turns out Bob can win $n=6$ with a start of $2$.  I will delete (and hopefully update) soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot awaiting for your update